# emacs+distel, api function auto remark

Tags: emacs, erlang

In emacs and distel developing environment, after writing some API for one module, is there any shortcut command to insert "doc" before the API signature? like following:

```
%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
%% @doc
%% 
%%
%% @spec
%% @end
%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this several ways... There is "Function" skeleton provided in fresh erlang-mode that inserts same header as you need. Another way - use any of template solutions, like [yasnippet](http://code.google.com/p/yasnippet/), or something like. And third way - use SRecode from CEDET to correctly generate header using parse information from your source code - see SRecode manual for examples...